# Why is exit code zero ("good") when I fail to handle an exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following code snippets and the resulting printouts from the console:

## Snippet 1

Behaves just ***fine***. Everything is hunkydory.

### Code

```
try:
    raise ValueError()
finally:
    print(3)
```

### Console Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/FILE_MGMT_PYTHON/fbzdfbhedrh.py", line 5, in <module>
    raise ValueError()
ValueError
3
```

## Snippet 2

Also behaves just ***fine***. Everything is hunkydory.

### Code

```
try:
    raise ValueError()
except type("", (Exception,), dict()):
    print("this is not supposed to print")
finally:
    print(3)
```

### Console Output

```
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/FILE_MGMT_PYTHON/fbzdfbhedrh.py", line 14, in <module>
    raise ValueError()
ValueError
```

## Snippet 3

I don't understand why the following does not result in an unhandled exception being printed to the console:

### Code

```
def e():
    try:
        raise ValueError()
        x = y + z
        L = [1, 2, 3]
        print(L[9999999999999999999999999999])
    except type("", (Exception,), dict()) as exc:
        print("this is not supposed to print")
        return "strawberries   " + src(exc)
    finally:
        return "finally"

print(e())
```

### Console Output

```
finally

Process finished with exit code 0
```

## Build:

```
------------------
System Information
------------------
      Time of this report: 10/25/2019, 07:22:01
             Machine name: DESKTOP-U5M46TJ
               Machine Id: {403D9006-3BF1-4C4B-AAF5-2AD795E00738}
         Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 18362) (18362.19h1_release.190318-1202)
                 Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
      System Manufacturer: System manufacturer
             System Model: System Product Name
                     BIOS: BIOS Date: 10/31/12 20:41:07 Ver: 36.02 (type: BIOS)
                Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500K CPU @ 3.30GHz (4 CPUs), ~3.3GHz
                   Memory: 4096MB RAM
      Available OS Memory: 4064MB RAM
                Page File: 12606MB used, 3744MB available
              Windows Dir: C:\Windows
          DirectX Version: DirectX 12
      DX Setup Parameters: Not found
         User DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
       System DPI Setting: 144 DPI (150 percent)
          DWM DPI Scaling: UnKnown
                 Miracast: Available, with HDCP
Microsoft Graphics Hybrid: Not Supported
 DirectX Database Version: Unknown
           DxDiag Version: 10.00.18362.0387 64bit Unicode

------------------
IDE Information
------------------
PyCharm 2019.1.3 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-191.7479.30, built on May 29, 2019
JRE: 11.0.2+9-b159.60 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

------------------
Python Information
------------------
print(sys.version)
print(sys.version_info)
print(sys.hexversion)

3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=8, micro=0, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
50856176
```

Comment: This is what I would expect to happen. More importantly, what do *you* expect to happen?

Comment: @SyntaxVoid I expect snippet 3 to raise and unhandled `ValueError`.

Comment: Exit codes must be set explicitly by the Python program. The Python interpreter can't know which exit code would be suitable in case of an exception. Therefore it sticks with zero.

Comment: Returning from a finally block discards the exception. The function can't return _and_ raise the exception, and you're telling it that you want it to return.

Comment: @khelwood. That's the confusing part. I didn't immediately see that either. It's worth posting an answer.

Comment: @MichaelButscher. But there is no exception...

Comment: I didn't immediately see it either, this question does not deserve a negative score

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I didn't notice that at first and concentrated on the title of the question.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Not since the "I'm writing this, and writing this, and writing this, and writing, and writing." was removed.

Comment: @khelwood. Yeah, I took out the emotional bits. It's a pretty legit question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Returning from a `finally` block discards the exception. The function can't return *and* raise the exception, and you're telling it that you want it to return.

The exception is going to be thrown, but before the `try` statement can be exited, the `finally` block needs to be run. Your `finally` block says "regardless of whatever you thought you were doing, I want to return". So the exception is discarded.

Similary, if you were *returning* from a `try` block, and the `finally` block raised an exception, the return value would be discarded.

See [Defining Clean-up Actions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions) in the Python docs:

> - If an exception occurs during execution of the `try` clause, the exception may be handled by an `except` clause. If the exception is not handled by an `except` clause, the exception is re-raised after the `finally` clause has been executed.
>     ...
> - If a `finally` clause includes a return statement, the `finally` clause’s return statement will execute before, and instead of, the return statement in a `try` clause.

Comment: Got it: Never **ever** ***EVER*** put a return statement inside of a `finally` clause. Otherwise, unhandled exceptions get swept under the rug and the program keeps running.

Answer (score -2):

The reason is your except statement.

```
>>> type("", (Exception,), dict())
<class '__main__.'>
```

And since a "ValueError" is not an exception of that type it won't catch the exception and will only go into the finally statement.
Change the except statement to:

```py
except ValueError as e:
    pass
# or this:
except Exception as e:
    pass
```

Comment: you're missing the point- the 3rd snippet does apparently catch the exception (that was the surprise)- khelwood explains why